# addClass and removeClass not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, addclass, removeclass

I have this code which checkes the top offset and changes the class of the menu accordingly.
It works perfectly, except in IE7 and IE8, where the class is not changed.
This is the code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() >= 800) {
$('#menu').removeClass('default').addClass('fixed');
}
else{$('#menu').removeClass('fixed').addClass('default');}
});
```

If anyone wants to have a look at, link is http://www.vivianzoric.com/esiq/index.html

p.s. Don't ask me why it falls apart in IE7, i only begin working on this yesterday:)

Comment: `Don't ask me why it falls apart in IE7` - I know it. Because IE is just ... IE

Comment: Do you know whether the `.scroll()` event is being called?  It's next to impossible for `addClass()` and `removeClass()` not to work (since all they do is read and set `.className`) so it's more likely that an event isn't working, `scrollTop()` isn't doing what you expect or a selector isn't doing what you expect.  You probably need to narrow down exactly which line of code isn't working right.

Comment: It could also be that you should be doing `.scrollTop()` on something other than the document object (perhaps `document.body`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using, `window` instead of `document`

```
$(window).scroll(function(){  } );
```

But keep `$(document).scrollTop(function()`

And just so you know, `.scrollTop` does work in IE (IE8 anyway)

**UPDATE**

Heres the exact code I currently use on one of my site

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= 800 ) ){
        //my code
    }else{
        //my code
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try.You can check the link i provided, everything works perfectly in all browsers, except IE7&8

Comment: Great, it worked.Could you please explain why this works in IE8, and document doesn't?

Comment: I'm not 100% but I'd assume that IE can't handle the `scroll` event on the document. But as the `window` overlays everything, it will always be called. Again I'm not 100%

Answer (score -1):

Problem in `scrollTop()` that doesn't work properly in IE

See http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Simply linking to the `scrollTop()` documentation is not enough... please explain this answer.

Comment: `scrolltop` does work in IE8 so I'd assume 9, not so sure about 7

Comment: RTFM, guys ;)

If you are not lazy and read the documentation completely, you would see a very helpful comments.
For example: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#comment-133682921

Comment: Maybe but I'm sure if @suludi is cpable of getting this far with their code, then I'm pretty sure they can lookup the JQuery Docs :)

Comment: But author of this question was thinking, that: "addClass and removeClass not working in IE" :(